# How to satisfy Boolean condition inside a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, boolean

I am working with a sample of the diamonds dataset. I need to write a function which should output the entries of the price column, for which the entries of the carat column are greater than the number 1.1 and less than 1.4.

Here is the sample data:

```
def exercise1(df,rowinds,colinds):
    df_1 = DataFrame(df)
    df_2 = df_1.iloc[rowinds, colinds]      
    return df_2

test_df = exercise1(diamonds,np.arange(500),np.arrange(10))
test_df
```

Here is my work so far:

```
def exercise2(df,col,output_label,val1,val2):
    df1 = DataFrame(df)
    df2 = DataFrame(df1,
        columns=[col])
    df3 = df2.rename(columns = {col:output_label})
    df4 = df3[df3 > val1]
    df5 = df4[df4 < val2]
    df6 = df5.dropna()
    return df6
```

The following test should return a series with the price of diamond numbers 172 and 376, however mine is returning the carat of diamond numbers 172 and 136.

```
test_df = exercise1(diamonds,np.arange(500),np.arange(10))
exercise2(test_df,test_df.carat,'price',1.1,1.4)
```

I can not figure out where I am going wrong.